# combine image and text on the fly and make whole div works as an hypelink

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, css

A picture worth thousands of words:

Question:

How to layout the image and text so they can work as an anchor as a whole?

[image]

Comment: @gov, I will. But as I am newbie on Javascript ,it will take me some time:)

Answer (score 0):

make your html

```
var varhtml="<div id="somid">// give background url as image
text goes here
</div>"

('#parentHtmlid').append(varhtml); or
('#parentHtmlid').html(varhtml); if you have place holder

$('#someid').live('click', function() { // as this id added at run time use live in document.ready//
   location.href="http://yoururl";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent element for both the image and the text, with `position: relative`. Each of its children should be `position: absolute`, with appropriate top/bottom left/right to line things up the way you want.